# How to add --help, -h flag to Thor command?

Tags: ruby, thor

I created a Thor class inside a Ruby executable, and it correctly shows the help when using `./foo help bar`.

To make it more intuitive (for the sanity of my users), I'd also like to support `./foo bar --help` and `./foo bar -h`.  When I do that, I get:

```
ERROR: "foo bar" was called with arguments ["--help"]
Usage: "foo bar"
```

I could manually do `method_option :help, ...` and handle it inside the `bar` method, but I hope there would be an easier way to do that (redirecting that command to `./foo help bar`).

Does anyone know a simple and easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Foo` is your class that inherits from `Thor`, you can call the following somewhere before `Foo.start`:

```
help_commands = Thor::HELP_MAPPINGS + ["help"]
# => ["-h", "-?", "--help", "-D"]

if help_commands.any? { |cmd| ARGV.include? cmd }
  help_commands.each do |cmd|
    if match = ARGV.delete(cmd)
      ARGV.unshift match
    end
  end
end
```

Rather than going into Thor and patching some method to have different ARGV-parsing behavior, this kind of cheats by moving any help commands to the front of the list.

Comment: I kinda wanted to avoid doing any ARGV stuff... But this works like a charm AND I just have to write it once, no matter how many commands I have.

Comment: I just changed the `unless` clause to `unless help_commands.include? ARGV[0]` as it seem a little bit more readable to me.

Comment: @RafaelSoares the entire point of this excersise was to accept help command at last position in ARGV. With your edit you have the original behavior of thor (first argument only). You can change it to `ARGV[-1]` if you want to handle beginnign or ennd of ARGV onnly.

Comment: Are you sure about that? `help_commands.any? { |cmd| ARGV[0] == cmd }` is the same as `help_commands.include? ARGV[0]` (see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F). You were right in your first approach, `--help` as the last argument is exactly what I was going for.

Comment: If one of those was my original code, it was a typo, what I meant was `help_commands.any? { |cmd| ARGV.include? cmd }`

Comment: That works if we use `if` instead of `unless` (I've tried it after my last comment). `if (help_commands & ARGV).any?` also works.

Comment: At any rate, I think you should revert your edit to your answer. It worked as it was, but it doesn't after the edit. If someone comes looking for the answer, they'll see something that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can achive this with `class_option`. If you set a class option this option is availiable for every method in your cli and you can just check if it is set and then call the help method.

Something like this:

```
class CLI < Thor
  class_option :help, type: :boolean

  desc "foo PARAM", "foo"
  def foo(param)
    handle_help_option(:foo)
    # your logic
  end

  def handle_help_option(method_name)
    help(method_name) if options[:help]
  end
end
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid having to add help-specific logic to all commands. Also, this executes the command after printing the help. Using your answer as a starting point, I could just write inside the `foo` command: `return help(:foo) if options[:help]`, which behaves correctly and avoids the extra method.

Comment: I just wish there was something like a `before_command` hook in Thor. I guess I'm too used to how Rails works. haha

Comment: @RafaelSoares kinda ugly but you could patch [Thor::Invocation#invoke_command](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/Thor/Invocation:invoke_command). However, in my opinion you have to weight the complexity of abstraction versus the amount of repetition it prevents. Sometimes it's not bad to have a little repetition. For example in your case you could define a central `setup` method which you manually call from each of the thor actions

Comment: You are right, you would have to return after the help hander method.

Answer (score 2):

Building on what @max-pleaner listed. This will support subcommands also:

```
help_commands = Thor::HELP_MAPPINGS + ["help"]
 (help_commands & ARGV).each do |cmd|
  match = ARGV.delete(cmd)
  ARGV.size > 1 ? ARGV.insert(-2, match) : ARGV.unshift(match)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement the answer from max pleaner, the following handles subcommands, because subcommands help is broken if the trick is applied to them.

Also, I choose to overload Thor start command.

```
def self.start(*args)
  if (Thor::HELP_MAPPINGS & ARGV).any? and subcommands.grep(/^#{ARGV[0]}/).empty?
    Thor::HELP_MAPPINGS.each do |cmd|
      if match = ARGV.delete(cmd)
        ARGV.unshift match
      end
    end
  end
  super
end
```

Comment: Any way to handle it also in registered subgroups? See https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/issues/532